# Seeking Easy Guide to ESA satellite data?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery, references, satellite

Can anybody provide user friendly guidance to ESA datasets?

What is available?

When will new stuff be available?

I struggle  to work out what might be interesting amongst the many websites and their somewhat verbose format. For example [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61476/best-source-for-high-resolution-satellite-images-free-low-cost/92203#92203) indicates that there is probably some high resolution imagery available or coming soon somewhere.... When I try to find anything I find [page](http://www.copernicus.eu/pages-principales/infrastructure/data-access/) after page after page about data access but very little information about the type of data itself.

The whole Copernicus Project looks fascinating!

I understand that it is all very new and many things aren't functioning yet nevertheless I would love to begin preparing ideas.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

check this site:  [ESA Earth Online](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/home;jsessionid=0BB7DB83F68B18AA8CCF1BB52A68483A.eodisp-prod4040).

if you have any doubt read this:
[EO data distributed by ESA](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/how-to-access-eo-data/earth-observation-data-distributed-by-esa)

And see [How to Access Data](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/how-to-access-eo-data/how-to-access-earth-observation-data-distributed-by-esa) webpage for details.

If you are interested in Copernicus Project check this [site](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/data-access/how-to-access-eo-data/gmes)

Comment: these are links I wanted to add in my initial post as examples of how inaccessible these data sets are. What I am looking for is a high level overview that keeps me updated as things come on line.

Comment: The content on these ESA pages seem friendly enough, you can browse the data products and find out about each one in more detail,  so that should help answer `What is available` and get product news so that should help answer `When will new stuff be available`